# QEMU installation error

Tags: software-installation

After compiling I got this error:

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in pixman
make  all-am
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
Making all in test
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
        CHK version_gen.h
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/share/qemu"
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/etc/qemu"
install -c -m 0644 /home/pi/qemu/qemu-1.6.0-rc1/sysconfigs/target/target-x86_64.conf "/usr/local/etc/qemu"
install: cannot remove `/usr/local/etc/qemu/target-x86_64.conf': Permission denied
Makefile:336: recipe for target 'install-sysconfig' failed
make: *** [install-sysconfig] Error 1
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: are you trying to install qemu on the Pi?

Comment: yea man.i got it.its work!
I was faced with many difficulties, but in the end everything works

Comment: Cool! Please post your resolution as an answer so others may benefit in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I got QEMU 1.6 running on RPi, my steps to the solution:

**Downloading qemu 1.6**

```
mkdir /home/pi/qemu && cd /home/pi/qemu

wget http://wiki.qemu-project.org/download/qemu-1.6.0-rc1.tar.bz2
```

**Unpack**

```
tar xfj qemu-1.6.0-rc1.tar.bz2
```

**Install dependencies**

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev libsdl1.2-dev bison flex
```

**Compile**

```
cd qemu-1.6.0-rc1

./configure --target-list="i386-softmmu i386-linux-user" --enable-sdl
--extra-cflags="-O3 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s
-mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6zk"
```

So we need one more lib

Download from here (in PC)

```
http://git.qemu-project.org/?p=dtc.git;a=snapshot;
h=1760e7ca03894689118646e229ca9487158cd0e8;sf=tgz
```

And extract it.
Rename folder containing the sources to `dtc` and place this folder in QEMU sources folder through WinSCP

Now

```
cd /home/pi/qemu/qemu-1.6.0-rc1.tar.bz2/dtc

make
```

Nice. We have dtc binaries

```
cd /home/pi/qemu/qemu-1.6.0-rc1.tar.bz2
```

One more lib: `gnutls`. My rep cant put links here. Find it in google ;) . Place in qemu1.6 folder, install it.

**Compile QEMU**

```
make
```

(about 1-2 hours)

```
sudo make install
```

(about 10sec)

Now we can start our qemu with your image

```
qemu -cpu 486 -hda /your/image.img -m 150m -smp 1 -redir tcp:2222::22 --nographic
```

Now we can connect to command prompt through putty (on port 2222).

I hope nothing is forgotten.

Comment: You should have enough rep to now add the links to the `gnutls` lib. I assume that it is [here](http://gnutls.org/download.html), but I didn't want to add the link in case I was wrong. If you could complete the steps covering the download and installation of `gnutls`, it would be very useful. Thanks.